# strcmp on char * compiles, but isn't working

Tags: c, linux, char, strtok, strcmp

I am trying to break up a char by spaces, then perform some conditional logic, but using strcmp on the char * isn't working.

```
int main(void)
{
    char buf[64];
    char *cmd;

    // assign some space delimited words to buf...

    if (strcmp(buf, "somestring junk") == 0) { // this works
        // do stuff here
    }

    cmd = strtok(buf, " ");

    if (strcmp(cmd, "somestring") == 0) { // this doesn't work
        // do stuff here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried different variations such as "somestring " or "somestring\n" to no success.  The code compiles without error or warning.  The man pages for strcmp lead me to believe strcmp should work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ***know*** you ran this in a debugger. (right??)  What does the debugger say is the actual value of `buf`?

Comment: Please provide a complete example -- help us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not working because you have the cmd and buf mixed up in strcmp. The following code should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[64] = "somestring junk";
    char *cmd;

    // assign some space delimited words to buf...

    if (strcmp(buf, "somestring junk") == 0)
    {
            printf("First strcmp works!\n");
    }

    cmd = strtok(buf, " ");

    if (strcmp(cmd, "somestring") == 0)
    {
        printf("Second strcmp works!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I will edit my code snip, but the problem persists.

Comment: Really? That's strange, I will research more into this when I'm on break again.

Comment: I found out the problem.  If I test without including a space in the test string, there is a trailing \n or some cr character.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: No problem, and I just edited my answer showing what I did to test it.